# How to downcast a Java object?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, downcast

I am trying to understand Java's polymorphism, and I have one question about downcasting an object.
Let's say for this example I have two subclasses Dog and Cat that inherit from a superclass Animal

From what I understood, the only way to downcast an object is if this Object is already of the good type, like this:

```
Animal a = new Dog();
Dog d = (Dog) a;
```

This works right?

But what if I want to create a regular animal without knowing what it would be, and then cast it when I know, how can I do that?

```
Animal a = new Animal();
Dog d = (Dog) a;
```

This will throw a ClassCastException at runtime right?

The only way I found to do that is to create a new Dog constructor that creates a dog from a regular animal:

```
Animal a = new Animal();
Dog d = new Dog(a);
```

with

```
public Class Dog extends Animal{
   public Dog(Animal a){
      super(a);
   }
}
```

So my question is, how am I supposed to do this?

- Am I doing it the best way?
- Am I not supposed to do this at all, if I have to it means my program is not well conceived?
- Is there a better way I missed?

Thanks a lot!
nbarraille

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to create an instance of a type that may vary depending upon non-local conditions, use an [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) (as described in the Design Patterns book).

In it's simplest form:

```
interface AnimalFactory {
    Animal createAnimal();
}

class DogFactory implements AnimalFactory {
    public Dog createAnimal() {
        return new Dog();
    }
}
```

Note also there is a difference between the static type of a reference and the dynamic type of the object. Even though you have an `Animal` reference, if the original object is a `Dog`, it still behaves like a `Dog`.

Answer (score 4):

You should only cast to a class that the object really is, so if you have a `Dog` that extends `Animal` you can cast it to an `Animal` (because it is one) but you shouldn't cast an `Animal` to a `Dog` because not all `Animal`s are `Dog`s. The `Dog` class may well have extra fields that are not implemented by the `Animal` class and so the cast doesn't make sense (what do you initialise those values to?).

Answer (score 1):

Java is a strongly typed language, and that means you can only cast an object to a type it extends from (either a superclass or an interface).

Even if you "fake it", e.g. copy all a classes methods and fields, you just can't cast an object to a type it doesn't extend.

```
public class Foo{

    public String phleem;

    public void bar(){

    }

}

public class Bar{

    public String phleem;

}

public interface Baz{

    public void bar();

}
```

Given the above code, you can't cast a `Foo` object to either a `Bar` or a `Baz`, although the class structure seems to imply that you could. There is no inheritance involved, so a `ClassCastException` is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are talking about downcasting, so in this scenario always superclass should be used as a reference and child object should be pointed by that. 
This usd basically in factory patter.