# Casting object of base class to derived class

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, object-oriented-analysis, downcast

I find myself in a tight spot. **I am building some logic on top of an existing project given to me in a jar. Hence I don't have the ability to modify these classes.**

I want to write additional methods to an existing class to make it feature rich . These methods would operate on few instance data and use some of the existing instance methods too.

But **since the class cannot be modified directly I am writing these additional methods in its new derived class.**  Consider the following example

```
public class Parent
{
  public void existing method()
  {

  }
} 


public class Child extends Parent
{
  public void newMethod()
  {

  }
}


public class Other
{
  public Parent foo()
  {
     Parent pr = new Parent();
     return pr;
  }
}

public class Test
{
   Other o = new Other();
   Parent p = o.foo;
   Child c = (Child) p;
   c.newMethod();
}
```

When I run this code I am getting a `ClassCastException`. I am aware i am downcasting. **Is there a way I can cast an object of base class to an object of derived class ?**

**If yes what would be a legitimate scenario in which one can downcast ?**

**If not then how should the above case be tackled ? . Should i be changing the design**

Appreciate your comments / suggestions !!!

Comment: When you are calling newMethod() ,why cant you call it on a derived class? like new Child().newMethod()?

Comment: Whats stopping you from creating a child class straightaway in Test? Child c = new Child()?

Comment: You should create an instance of Child in method foo(). Or it's for some reasons impossible?

Comment: @KumarAbhinav please refer to the above example. I have to call the foo method of "Other" class which returns an object of "parent" class . The newMethod has the operation that I want to perform on the data members of p belonging to the parent class

Comment: i hope this clears up as to why I cannot create an instance of the child class directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do go against the concept of polymophism and heritage, you can only put a child object into a parent object, since they share the same base properties, but you cannot try to cast a parent into his child.

I would suggest to create a "cast" method in your Other class where you would take everything that matters in the child then create a parent object with that data and return it.

Something like this :

```
public Parent downcast(Child c)
{
    Parent cast = new Parent();
    //Transfer data from the child to the parent
    cast.setProperty(c.getProperty());
    return cast;
}
```

There is probably a better solution than this, but it could solve your problem easily.

## Update

This could help you too, maybe a duplicate? : [How to downcast a Java object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033118/how-to-downcast-a-java-object?rq=1)